# Moving installed apps on Android to external storage

Tags: android, package-managers

My requirement is to be able to move all apps installed on the device(tablet) to an external SD card with the click of a button.

My research says, unless a .apk file have a manifest attribute `installLocation` specified as `auto` or `preferExternal`, the app cannot be moved.

Using `PackageManager` class allows me to get a list of all files installed on the device.
But I cannot find how to move an app, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to move apps to external storage if they are not specified as being allowed to, unless your device is rooted.

Comment: Each of the apps that would be installed would have a manifest attribute installLocation of auto. So yes they can be moved between internal and external storage. My question is how or what classes would be used to achieve that. Thanks